# Openstack install on 16

Tags: 16.04, openstack, conjure-up

I'm running into issues installing Openstack on 14.04. See https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/450 This is apparently due to the fact that my Ethernet interfaces are not eth0 / eth1. Seeing as that's no longer how interfaces are named, how does one work around that?

```
juju-2.0 2.0~beta15-0ubuntu2.16.04.1
conjure-up 2.0.1~beta2-0~201609281246~ubuntu16.04.1 all
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are asking about **conjure-up** which is only supported on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) and newer. Your question is confusing because you mentioned 14.04.

Second, I had answered this question in your github issue. To reiterate, you want to set `net.ifaces=0` in your **MAAS Settings page** under **Global Kernel Parameters**.

There are other issues with this post like not mentioning you're using **MAAS**.

This should answer your question about the network interfaces being renamed.